# Not seeing expected output from json:transform-from-json and fn:tokenize

Tags: marklogic

We have two REST extensions. Both expect CSV data from client. We pass in the exact same data via json. The messages comming in are identical, we do a `xdmp:log($input)` of the received json message on the server, identical:

```
2014-08-28 12:06:13.443 Info: STRLF3: START VERTALER ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2014-08-28 12:06:13.443 Info: STRLF3: {"ID":"","DingenID":"","VertaalType":"VAN6NAARWIJK","Name":"Vertaling-28-Aug-2014 12:08.txt","Text":"PC,Verkoopprijs\n1000AK,89.99\n1000EA,49.99\n1001GM,100\n1001LA,34.99\n1001MJ,24.99\n1011AC,19.98\n1011AC,20.99\n1011AC,9.98\n1011AC,30.98\n1011BT,999.01\n1011CD,30\n1011DJ,12\n1011DJ,100.98\n1011DJ,99.98\n1011DJ,24.99\n1011DK,18.98\n1011EG,28.98\n1011EK,93.97\n1011EK,50.99\n1011ET,51.49\n1011EZ,51.99\n1011GA,24.99\n1011GD,34.99\n1011GR,35.99\n1011GW,29.99\n1011GW,24.99\n1011HB,14.98\n1011HB,29.99\n1011HB,65.45\n1011HB,28.79\n1011HL,49.99\n1011JH,18.98\n1011JH,19.99\n1011JH,14.98\n1011JX,70\n1011KC,54.98\n1011KK,100\n1011KX,43.98\n1011LE,119\n1011LL,49.99\n1011LL,4.99\n1011LM,64.99\n1011LM,39.95\n1011LS,13.97\n1011LX,20\n1011LZ,29.99\n1011LZ,16.99\n1011MG,49.99\n1011MH,100\n1011MH,79.99\n1011MH,72\n1011MK,31.99\n1011ML,48.98\n1011ML,24.99\n1011ML,83.97\n1011MN,23.98\n1011MN,35.97\n1011MR,30.99\n1011NA,19.8\n1011NC,24.99\n1011NK,73.98\n1011NV,12\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,9.98\n1011NV,4.99\n1011NV,12\n1011PG,50\n1011PG,39.98\n1011PG,24.99\n1011PL,35\n1011PL,366.01\n1011RH,23.99\n1011SG,8.98\n1011SG,10\n1011SP,50.99\n1011SZ,73.98\n1011TB,59.99\n1011TB,49.99\n1011TE,253.01\n1011TE,23.88\n1011TE,9.08\n1011TL,28\n1011TL,9.98\n1011TR,14.99\n1011TR,14.98\n1011TR,13.98\n1011TZ,33.97\n1011VB,220\n1011VZ,38.97\n1011WD,13.97\n1012AC,66.97\n1012AE,15.98\n1012AL,43.98\n1012AL,50.99\n1012BA,19.99\n1012BE,59.99\n1012BJ,29.99\n1012BJ,33.99"}
```

Log message from API2 call:

```
2014-08-28 12:07:42.264 Info: STRLF3: ++++++++++++++++++ START TRANSACTIONS ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2014-08-28 12:07:42.264 Info: STRLF3: {"ID":"","DingenID":"","ProjectID":268393,"Name":"Transactiedata-28-Aug-2014 12:08.txt","Text":"PC,Verkoopprijs\n1000AK,89.99\n1000EA,49.99\n1001GM,100\n1001LA,34.99\n1001MJ,24.99\n1011AC,19.98\n1011AC,20.99\n1011AC,9.98\n1011AC,30.98\n1011BT,999.01\n1011CD,30\n1011DJ,12\n1011DJ,100.98\n1011DJ,99.98\n1011DJ,24.99\n1011DK,18.98\n1011EG,28.98\n1011EK,93.97\n1011EK,50.99\n1011ET,51.49\n1011EZ,51.99\n1011GA,24.99\n1011GD,34.99\n1011GR,35.99\n1011GW,29.99\n1011GW,24.99\n1011HB,14.98\n1011HB,29.99\n1011HB,65.45\n1011HB,28.79\n1011HL,49.99\n1011JH,18.98\n1011JH,19.99\n1011JH,14.98\n1011JX,70\n1011KC,54.98\n1011KK,100\n1011KX,43.98\n1011LE,119\n1011LL,49.99\n1011LL,4.99\n1011LM,64.99\n1011LM,39.95\n1011LS,13.97\n1011LX,20\n1011LZ,29.99\n1011LZ,16.99\n1011MG,49.99\n1011MH,100\n1011MH,79.99\n1011MH,72\n1011MK,31.99\n1011ML,48.98\n1011ML,24.99\n1011ML,83.97\n1011MN,23.98\n1011MN,35.97\n1011MR,30.99\n1011NA,19.8\n1011NC,24.99\n1011NK,73.98\n1011NV,12\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,9.98\n1011NV,4.99\n1011NV,12\n1011PG,50\n1011PG,39.98\n1011PG,24.99\n1011PL,35\n1011PL,366.01\n1011RH,23.99\n1011SG,8.98\n1011SG,10\n1011SP,50.99\n1011SZ,73.98\n1011TB,59.99\n1011TB,49.99\n1011TE,253.01\n1011TE,23.88\n1011TE,9.08\n1011TL,28\n1011TL,9.98\n1011TR,14.99\n1011TR,14.98\n1011TR,13.98\n1011TZ,33.97\n1011VB,220\n1011VZ,38.97\n1011WD,13.97\n1012AC,66.97\n1012AE,15.98\n1012AL,43.98\n1012AL,50.99\n1012BA,19.99\n1012BE,59.99\n1012BJ,29.99\n1012BJ,33.99"}
```

Then we go into this part of the code:

In API 1 we have:

```
        let $_ := xdmp:log("START VERTALER ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        let $_ := xdmp:log($input)

        let $id         := sl3:get-id("/app/vertaler/", "json")
        let $uri        := fn:concat("/app/vertaler/", $id, ".xml")
        let $xml        := json:transform-from-json($input)
        let $vertaaltype:= $xml//jbasic:VertaalType/text()
        let $fileID     := $xml//jbasic:ID/text()
              let $preurl     := 'http://streetlife.dikw.com'

        (: do vertaal magic here ... :)
        let $text := $xml//jbasic:Text/text()

        let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("Recieved text data, raw: ", $input))
        let $codes := fn:tokenize($text,'\n')
        (: check if tokenization is ok :)
        let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("Recieved text data, count: ", fn:count($codes)))
```

Result API1:

```
2014-08-28 12:06:13.445 Info: STRLF3: Recieved text data, count: 100
```

We see the file is parsed correctly.

In API 2 we have:

```
    let $project  := json:transform-from-json($input)/ns:ProjectID
    let $codes    := json:transform-from-json($input)/ns:Text
    let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("123 Recieved text data, raw: ", $input))

    let $text     := fn:tokenize($codes,'&#10;') (: &#10; of '/n'  :)
    let $_ := xdmp:log(fn:concat("Recieved text data, count: ", fn:count($text)))
```

Result API 2 with `\n` as tokenize character:

```
2014-08-28 12:07:42.266 Info: STRLF3: Recieved text data, count: 1
```

API 1 needs fn:tokenize($text,'\n') and API2 needs fn:tokenize($codes,'& #10;'). The extra space is intentional.

What is the expected outcome of `json:transform-from-json`? The behavior of API 1 or 2, or put it differently do I need to tokenize with `\n` or `&#10;`? As you can see I have two apis each working but not working with the other value in the tokenize function...

What puzzles me is that I have checked line for line, including loading of namespaces and module and still I cannot find the difference.

Comment: Add the "Recieved text data, raw" log message, so we can see the text that needs to be tokenized.

Comment: it is in the above first and second code blocks, last line is rather long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a problem with newline escaping.

```
xdmp:to-json(
  'line 1
line 2')

=> "line 1\nline 2"
```

Now try adding `tokenize`:

```
xdmp:to-json(
  'line 1
line 2')
! tokenize(., '\n')

=> "line 1\nline 2"
```

That doesn't do anything, because `tokenize` treats its second parameter as a regex. So the regex `\n` matches a literal newline character, whereas the newline in the input is actually two characters `\` and `n`.

```
xdmp:to-json(
  'line 1
line 2')
! tokenize(., '\\n')

=> "line 1
line 2"
```

That's closer to what we might want. I probably don't want the double-quote characters in the output, either. But this is just meant to show how newline escaping might be the problem.

Comment: but still that does not say way in one api fn:tokenize($text,'\n') works and in the other not... there i need fn:tokenize($codes,'&#10;') for the tokenizer to split >>the same << content ...?

Comment: what representation of the newline should come out of the json:transform-from-json() in the default setting? XML thus that mean that the newline is also translated into an HTML representation aka codepoint(10)  ..?

Comment: See for yourself: `json:transform-from-json('["\n"]')/*[1] ! string-to-codepoints(.)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't supply a configuration on the call to json:transform-from-json(), the result is XML in the "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic" namespace.

The first example binds the jsbasic prefix to that namespace and uses a descendant XPath ("//") to pull out the properties.

Assuming the second example binds the ns prefix to the .../json/basic namespace, the XPaths try to match the properties at the root.  The root in the XML generated by a transform-to-json without configuration is always "json" (with the namespace), so the XPaths won't match.  Depending on the structure of the JSON, it might work to use a descendant XPath ("//") as in the first example.

In the second example, you also probably want to capture the output from json:transform-from-json() in a variable for efficiency, as in:

```
let $xml      := json:transform-from-json($input)
let $project  := $xml//ns:ProjectID
let $codes    := $xml//ns:Text
```

If that doesn't work, try logging $xml to inspect the output from the transform.

Here's the documentation:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_93718
- http://docs.marklogic.com/json:config?q=json:config

Comment: thx for your repsponse but the example shows we find the text alright that is not the issue. problem is when we tokenize the first needs /n the second needs the codepoint(10) to tokenize ... no clue why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what the problem is, but this works for me with 7.0-3:

```
let $input := '{"ID":"","DingenID":"","ProjectID":268393,"Name":"Transactiedata-28-Aug-2014 12:08.txt","Text":"PC,Verkoopprijs\n1000AK,89.99\n1000EA,49.99\n1001GM,100\n1001LA,34.99\n1001MJ,24.99\n1011AC,19.98\n1011AC,20.99\n1011AC,9.98\n1011AC,30.98\n1011BT,999.01\n1011CD,30\n1011DJ,12\n1011DJ,100.98\n1011DJ,99.98\n1011DJ,24.99\n1011DK,18.98\n1011EG,28.98\n1011EK,93.97\n1011EK,50.99\n1011ET,51.49\n1011EZ,51.99\n1011GA,24.99\n1011GD,34.99\n1011GR,35.99\n1011GW,29.99\n1011GW,24.99\n1011HB,14.98\n1011HB,29.99\n1011HB,65.45\n1011HB,28.79\n1011HL,49.99\n1011JH,18.98\n1011JH,19.99\n1011JH,14.98\n1011JX,70\n1011KC,54.98\n1011KK,100\n1011KX,43.98\n1011LE,119\n1011LL,49.99\n1011LL,4.99\n1011LM,64.99\n1011LM,39.95\n1011LS,13.97\n1011LX,20\n1011LZ,29.99\n1011LZ,16.99\n1011MG,49.99\n1011MH,100\n1011MH,79.99\n1011MH,72\n1011MK,31.99\n1011ML,48.98\n1011ML,24.99\n1011ML,83.97\n1011MN,23.98\n1011MN,35.97\n1011MR,30.99\n1011NA,19.8\n1011NC,24.99\n1011NK,73.98\n1011NV,12\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,19.99\n1011NV,9.98\n1011NV,4.99\n1011NV,12\n1011PG,50\n1011PG,39.98\n1011PG,24.99\n1011PL,35\n1011PL,366.01\n1011RH,23.99\n1011SG,8.98\n1011SG,10\n1011SP,50.99\n1011SZ,73.98\n1011TB,59.99\n1011TB,49.99\n1011TE,253.01\n1011TE,23.88\n1011TE,9.08\n1011TL,28\n1011TL,9.98\n1011TR,14.99\n1011TR,14.98\n1011TR,13.98\n1011TZ,33.97\n1011VB,220\n1011VZ,38.97\n1011WD,13.97\n1012AC,66.97\n1012AE,15.98\n1012AL,43.98\n1012AL,50.99\n1012BA,19.99\n1012BE,59.99\n1012BJ,29.99\n1012BJ,33.99"}'
let $m := xdmp:from-json($input)
let $text as xs:string := map:get($m, 'Text')
let $records := tokenize($text, '\n')
let $labels := tokenize($records[1], ',')
let $data := subsequence($records, 2)
for $i in $data
let $seq := tokenize($i, ',')
return text { $labels[1], $seq[1], $labels[2], $seq[2] }
```

I used `xdmp:from-json` to parse the JSON, instead of `json:transform-from-json`. I'm not sure if that makes any different to the newline processing, but it returns a json dictionary object. That's like a map:map item, except that the keys are ordered.

Anyway this returns:

```
PC 1000AK Verkoopprijs 89.99
PC 1000EA Verkoopprijs 49.99
PC 1001GM Verkoopprijs 100
PC 1001LA Verkoopprijs 34.99
...
```

You can also do it with `json:transform-from-json`. Replace the assignment of `$m` and `$text` with:

```
let $text as xs:string := json:transform-from-json($input)/xjb:Text
```

Tokenizing on `&#10;` works equally well for me with either code sample.